# Как сделать, чтобы гифки играла один раз?

Tags: python, qt, qt5, pyqt5, pyqt

Не могу найти такой же вопрос. Нужно, чтобы `гифки проигрывалась только один раз`, а не бесконечно.

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Чем гифки отображаете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets    import *
from PyQt5.QtCore       import *
from PyQt5.QtGui        import *
import random

# Создайте список каких-то .gif
list_of_gifs = ['loading.gif', 
                'animated-dancing-image-0028.gif', 
                'D:/_Qt/img/spir.gif', 
                'D:/_Qt/__Qt/892768447/QLabel/Data/foo.gif'
               ] 

class GIFLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, gifs, *args, **kwargs):
        QLabel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.mGifs = gifs
        self.changeGIF()

    def changeGIF(self):
        gif = random.choice(self.mGifs)
        self.movie = QMovie(gif)       
        self.setMovie(self.movie)

        # Возвращает количество кадров в фильме.
        self.frame_count = self.movie.frameCount() 

        # Этот сигнал испускается, когда номер кадра изменился на frameNumber. 
        self.movie.frameChanged.connect(self.frame_Changed)  # +

        self.movie.start()


    def frame_Changed(self, v):
        if self.frame_count == v + 1:
            # print(v)
            self.movie.stop()


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300, 300)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.btn = QPushButton("Загрузите случайную .gif", self)
        self.label = GIFLabel(list_of_gifs, self)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)        
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.label.changeGIF)
        self.grid = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label)
        self.grid.addStretch(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MyApp = Window()
    MyApp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> проблема что гифки останавливается и остается на экране застывшая картинка, как ее убрать после stop?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets    import *
from PyQt5.QtCore       import *
from PyQt5.QtGui        import *
import random

# Создайте список каких-то .gif
list_of_gifs = ['loading.gif', 
                'animated-dancing-image-0028.gif', 
                'D:/_Qt/img/spir.gif', 
                'D:/_Qt/__Qt/892768447/QLabel/Data/foo.gif'
               ] 

class GIFLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, gifs, *args, **kwargs):
        QLabel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.mGifs = gifs
        self.changeGIF()

    def changeGIF(self):
        self.show()                                                    # +++

        gif = random.choice(self.mGifs)
        self.movie = QMovie(gif)       
        self.setMovie(self.movie)

        # Возвращает количество кадров в фильме.
        self.frame_count = self.movie.frameCount() 

        # Этот сигнал испускается, когда номер кадра изменился на frameNumber. 
        self.movie.frameChanged.connect(self.frame_Changed)  

        self.movie.start()


    def frame_Changed(self, v):
        if self.frame_count == v + 1:
            # print(v)
            self.movie.stop()

            self.hide()                                                  # +++


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300, 300)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.btn = QPushButton("Загрузите случайную .gif", self)
        self.label = GIFLabel(list_of_gifs, self)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)        
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.label.changeGIF)
        self.grid = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label)
        self.grid.addStretch(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MyApp = Window()
    MyApp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: проблема что гифки останавливается и остается на экране застывшая картинка, как ее убрать после stop?

Comment: @whyeaye я добавил обновление. Проблем нет :)