# Как перед открытием главного окна, запустить загрузочное окно-заставку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qt-designer, qsplashscreen

Я хочу сделать, чтобы перед открытием приложения на пять секунд или до открытия главного окна, открывалось загрузочное окно, в котором будет написано 
**`"Ожидайте загрузки приложения"`** и проигрывалась какая-нибудь гифка.

Вот что-то похожее как у дискорда. Я сделал это загрузочное окно (**eow.py**), может быть через него это как-то можно сделать?

---

**unt.py** - главное окно:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(732, 538)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 731, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(30)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 120, 711, 161))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.horizontalScrollBar = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalScrollBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 496, 731, 20))
        self.horizontalScrollBar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalScrollBar.setObjectName("horizontalScrollBar")
        self.verticalScrollBar = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalScrollBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(711, 0, 20, 501))
        self.verticalScrollBar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.verticalScrollBar.setObjectName("verticalScrollBar")
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 280, 711, 211))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(50)
        self.spinBox.setFont(font)
        self.spinBox.setButtonSymbols(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.NoButtons)
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 90, 711, 31))
        self.progressBar.setStyleSheet("")
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 22)
        self.progressBar.setTextVisible(False)
        self.progressBar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.progressBar.setTextDirection(QtWidgets.QProgressBar.TopToBottom)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 732, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuF = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuF.setObjectName("menuF")
        self.menuRE = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuF)
        self.menuRE.setObjectName("menuRE")
        self.menuRE1_2 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuRE)
        self.menuRE1_2.setObjectName("menuRE1_2")
        self.menuRE_2 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuF)
        self.menuRE_2.setObjectName("menuRE_2")
        self.menuRE1 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuRE_2)
        self.menuRE1.setObjectName("menuRE1")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.actionRE2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionRE2.setObjectName("actionRE2")
        self.actionRE2_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionRE2_2.setObjectName("actionRE2_2")
        self.menuRE1_2.addAction(self.actionRE2_2)
        self.menuRE.addAction(self.menuRE1_2.menuAction())
        self.menuRE1.addAction(self.actionRE2)
        self.menuRE_2.addAction(self.menuRE1.menuAction())
        self.menuF.addAction(self.menuRE_2.menuAction())
        self.menuF.addAction(self.menuRE.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuF.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ГЛАВНОЕ ОКНО"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пишите..."))
        self.menuF.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "F"))
        self.menuRE.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "RE"))
        self.menuRE1_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "RE1"))
        self.menuRE_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "RE"))
        self.menuRE1.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "RE1"))
        self.actionRE2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RE2"))
        self.actionRE2_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RE2"))

class Exm(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Exm()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**eow.py** - загрузочное окно:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(342, 355)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 280, 331, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 341, 251))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;")
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ожидайте открытия программы..."))

class Exm1(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)  

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Exm1()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Смотрите в сторону `QSplashScreen`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423781/using-a-gif-in-splash-screen-in-pyqt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сначала мы создаем экземпляр элемента управления `QSplashScreen`, 
вызываем метод `setPixmap()` для установки изображения, а
 затем вызываем метод `show()` для его отображения.

Метод `showMessage(str, alignment, color)` отображает `текст` на экране запуска программы.
 `Выравнивание` - это положение текста на заставке, здесь мы устанавливаем
 вверху по центру, `color` - цвет текста мы устанавливаем его белым.

Поскольку запуск программы не занимает много времени, заставка будет мигать, 
поэтому мы добавляем сюда строку `QtCore.QThread.msleep(5000)`, чтобы сделать паузу на 5 секунд,  чтобы увидеть эффект.

Когда мы решим, что можем начать отображать главное окно, мы можем вызвать `finish()`, 
чтобы передать экземпляр главного окна.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(732, 538)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 731, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(30)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 120, 711, 161))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.horizontalScrollBar = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalScrollBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 496, 731, 20))
        self.horizontalScrollBar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalScrollBar.setObjectName("horizontalScrollBar")
        self.verticalScrollBar = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalScrollBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(711, 0, 20, 501))
        self.verticalScrollBar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.verticalScrollBar.setObjectName("verticalScrollBar")
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 280, 711, 211))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(50)
        self.spinBox.setFont(font)
        self.spinBox.setButtonSymbols(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.NoButtons)
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 90, 711, 31))
        self.progressBar.setStyleSheet("")
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 22)
        self.progressBar.setTextVisible(False)
        self.progressBar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.progressBar.setTextDirection(QtWidgets.QProgressBar.TopToBottom)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 732, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuF = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuF.setObjectName("menuF")
        self.menuRE = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuF)
        self.menuRE.setObjectName("menuRE")
        self.menuRE1_2 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuRE)
        self.menuRE1_2.setObjectName("menuRE1_2")
        self.menuRE_2 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuF)
        self.menuRE_2.setObjectName("menuRE_2")
        self.menuRE1 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuRE_2)
        self.menuRE1.setObjectName("menuRE1")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.actionRE2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionRE2.setObjectName("actionRE2")
        self.actionRE2_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionRE2_2.setObjectName("actionRE2_2")
        self.menuRE1_2.addAction(self.actionRE2_2)
        self.menuRE.addAction(self.menuRE1_2.menuAction())
        self.menuRE1.addAction(self.actionRE2)
        self.menuRE_2.addAction(self.menuRE1.menuAction())
        self.menuF.addAction(self.menuRE_2.menuAction())
        self.menuF.addAction(self.menuRE.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuF.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ГЛАВНОЕ ОКНО"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пишите..."))
        self.menuF.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "F"))
        self.menuRE.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "RE"))
        self.menuRE1_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "RE1"))
        self.menuRE_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "RE"))
        self.menuRE1.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "RE1"))
        self.actionRE2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RE2"))
        self.actionRE2_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RE2"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    splash = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen()
    splash.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('images/splash.jpg'))
    splash.show()
    splash.showMessage('<h1 style="color:white;">Добро пожаловать в этот заставка, сделанная в PyQt5</h1>', 
                       QtCore.Qt.AlignTop | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter, QtCore.Qt.white)    

    QtCore.QThread.msleep(5000)   # 

    demo = MainWindow()
    demo.show()
    splash.finish(demo)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> возник вопрос, как вставить гиф, если просто прописать вместо jpg то она выглядит как обычная картинка

Попробую показать пример более-менее реальной задачи.

**Note**: Вы должны выполнить трудоемкую задачу в другом потоке 
и подать сигнал, что задача завершена.

```
import sys
import threading
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


def consuming_work(arg1, arg2):
    import time

    print(arg1, arg2)
    time.sleep(5)                               #  Какая-то трудоемкая задача
    print("finish")


class WorkerMessageBox(QtWidgets.QMessageBox):
    started  = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.finished.connect(self.accept)
        self.move(450, 420)

    def execute(self, func, args):
        threading.Thread(target=self._execute, args=(func, args,), daemon=True).start()
        return self.exec_()

    def _execute(self, func, args):
        self.started.emit()
        func(*args)                             #  Вызываем трудоемкую задачу  
        self.finished.emit()


class GifLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QLabel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.setWindowFlags(
              QtCore.Qt.Window 
            | QtCore.Qt.Tool 
            | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint
            | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
            | QtCore.Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)        

        self.movie = QtGui.QMovie('D:/_Qt/__Qt/loading.gif')       
        self.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(732, 538)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 731, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(30)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 120, 711, 161))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.horizontalScrollBar = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalScrollBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 496, 731, 20))
        self.horizontalScrollBar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalScrollBar.setObjectName("horizontalScrollBar")
        self.verticalScrollBar = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalScrollBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(711, 0, 20, 501))
        self.verticalScrollBar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.verticalScrollBar.setObjectName("verticalScrollBar")
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 280, 711, 211))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(50)
        self.spinBox.setFont(font)
        self.spinBox.setButtonSymbols(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.NoButtons)
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 90, 711, 31))
        self.progressBar.setStyleSheet("")
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 22)
        self.progressBar.setTextVisible(False)
        self.progressBar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.progressBar.setTextDirection(QtWidgets.QProgressBar.TopToBottom)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 732, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuF = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuF.setObjectName("menuF")
        self.menuRE = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuF)
        self.menuRE.setObjectName("menuRE")
        self.menuRE1_2 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuRE)
        self.menuRE1_2.setObjectName("menuRE1_2")
        self.menuRE_2 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuF)
        self.menuRE_2.setObjectName("menuRE_2")
        self.menuRE1 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuRE_2)
        self.menuRE1.setObjectName("menuRE1")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.actionRE2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionRE2.setObjectName("actionRE2")
        self.actionRE2_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionRE2_2.setObjectName("actionRE2_2")
        self.menuRE1_2.addAction(self.actionRE2_2)
        self.menuRE.addAction(self.menuRE1_2.menuAction())
        self.menuRE1.addAction(self.actionRE2)
        self.menuRE_2.addAction(self.menuRE1.menuAction())
        self.menuF.addAction(self.menuRE_2.menuAction())
        self.menuF.addAction(self.menuRE.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuF.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ГЛАВНОЕ ОКНО"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пишите..."))
        self.menuF.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "F"))
        self.menuRE.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "RE"))
        self.menuRE1_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "RE1"))
        self.menuRE_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "RE"))
        self.menuRE1.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "RE1"))
        self.actionRE2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RE2"))
        self.actionRE2_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RE2"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    gifLabel = GifLabel()
    gifLabel.show() 

    msgBox = WorkerMessageBox()
    msgBox.setWindowTitle("Working ....")
    msgBox.setText("Работает, пожалуйста подождите ...")
    msgBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.NoButton)        

    msgBox.execute(consuming_work, ["Stack", "Overflow"])

    demo = MainWindow()
    gifLabel.movie.stop()
    gifLabel.hide()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: возник вопрос, как вставить гиф, если просто прописать вместо jpg то она выглядит как обычная картинка

Comment: @imapw_  о gifках я уже пару раз отвечал, посмотрите здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/850016/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-qtread-%d0%b2-pyqt5/850296#850296 и здесь  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1055949/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7/1056016#1056016